# Venues/SuggestCompletion doesn't give any results

Tags: foursquare

I know for a fact that there are atleast 5-6 POI within the 50 mile radius in this area. However, I don't get any results on this query.
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestCompletion?ll=-44.67,167.92&query=milford&radius=50000

I see results when I try search api (it doesnt use query as mentioned in documentation):
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-44.67,167.92&intent=checkin&query=milford&radius=50000

No results with intent match on the search query.

I really like the suggestcompletion api (compact). Any suggestion/input would be great?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The suggestcompletion endpoint is used to suggest venues whose names start with the provided query. The endpoint is used to provide autocomplete results for search input fields. It is not used as a general purpose venue search - you should use the `/venues/search` endpoint for this purpose.

Comment: i am using it for names start with only. the ll around which i am searching has venues/poi's starting with "milford" but it doesnt show up in suggest completion api.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have missed out the API version param. You need to denote it by adding this into your request :

&v=20150826

suggestCompletion is included into newer API released on 20150826 which differs from default one that not including suggestCompletion feature.